# Export DIV to PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

So i am trying to export a specific `div` to a PDF file and i am failing miserably...
This is the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testpage</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/jquery.dataTable.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/toastr.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/chart.css" />
  <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
  <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->
 </head>
 <body>

  <!-- Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Main -->
     <div id="main">
      <div class="inner" id="inner">

       <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
         <h2><a href="#" class="logo"><strong>Test</strong></a></h2>
        </header>

       <!-- Content -->
        <section>

         <!-- Table -->
         <h3>Table</h3>

         <div class="table-wrapper">
          <table id="myTable">
           <thead>
           <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Speed</th>
            <th>Meters</th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>

            <?php
             require_once ('showData.php');
            ?>
        </section>

      </div>
     </div>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
     <div class="inner">

      <!-- Menü -->
      <nav id="menu">
       <header class="major">
        <h2>Menü</h2>
       </header>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li>
         <span class="opener">Test</span>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Test1</a></li>
          <li><a href="test2.php">Test2</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </nav>

      <!-- Filter -->
      <section>
       <header class="major">
        <h2>Filter</h2>
       </header>
                            <form method="post" id="submitdata" name="submitdata">
                                <div class="row uniform">
                                    <div class="12u 12u$">
                                        <input type="text" name="datefrom" id="datefrom" value="" placeholder="Date from" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u 12u$">
                                        <input type="text" name="dateto" id="dateto" value="" placeholder="Date to" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <div class="select-wrapper">
                                            <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
                                                <option value="0">- Choose -</option>
                                                <option value="1">All</option>
                                                <option value="2">Speed</option>
                                                <option value="3">Meter</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="12u$">
                                        <ul class="actions">
                                            <li><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Clickme" class="special" /></li>
                                            <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
      </section>

                        <!-- Exportmenü -->
                        <section>
                            <header class="major">
                                <h2>Export</h2>
                            </header>
                            <div class="12u 12u$">
                                <button id="btnExport" class="button special icon fa-file-pdf-o">Export as PDF</button>
                            </div>
                        </section>

      <!-- Footer -->
                        <footer id="footer">
                            <p> Stuff </p>
                        </footer>

     </div>
    </div>

   </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="../assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
   <script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/toastr.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/js/submitData.js"></script>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
                    });
                });
            </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get everything in `<div class="inner" id="inner">` into an PDF-File but nothing seems to work. I tried with jsPDF and html2canvas (html -> img -> pdf) but the quality is VERY bad. Nothing else seems to work.
I would appreciate some pointers like what i can use to get it working.

Thank you very much,
Skar

EDIT:
This is what i included after the jsPDF recommendation

```html
            <script src="../assets/jsPDF/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
            <script src="../assets/jsPDF/examples/js/html2canvas.js"></script>

            <script>

                var doc = new jsPDF();

                var specialElementHandlers = {
                    '#header': function(element, renderer){
                        return true;
                    }
                };


                $('#btnExport').click(function(){
                    var html=$("#inner").html();
                    doc.fromHTML(html,0,0, {
                        'width': 500,
                        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                    });
                    doc.save("Test.pdf");
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an HTML problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library, it is built for client side PDF generation.

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf

[Here is the github link](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

Comment: It is kind of working, i guess ;P
I get a PDF file, but i am not able to use it like this. I edited the code in my post. Part of the data in the `div` gets processed into google charts, but all i get are tables with the data. Is there a way to export the `div` the way i "see" it?

Comment: jsPDF is not working as it doesn't render css and you can't make it look like the page.

Comment: @Skar have you found a solution to that?

Comment: Yes, including CSS is important, I don't think `jspdf` can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `jspdf`, you might be a lot better off using `html2pdf.js`, see https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js.

It basically comes down to this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_report_print_button').click(function () {
    var my_filename = $('#my_element').val() + '.pdf';
    var element = document.getElementById('my_print_area_id');
    html2pdf()
      .from(element)
      .set({
        margin: 0,
        filename: my_filename,
        html2canvas: { scale: 5 }, // Use a higher scale for better quality
        jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'landscape' }
      })
      .save();
  });
});
```

This perfectly captures all of the CSS and is pretty much identical to using the print function of the browser, except that you can give it a specific `<div>`!

I use it in [Shiny](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/), by doing nothing more than adding:

```r
includeScript("www/html2pdf.bundle.min.js")
```